# What is the most powerful FPGA that yosys / Project IceStorm will target?

Tags: fpga, riscv, yosys

I have written an integer RISC-V-64 CPU in verilog.  It builds with Verilator and passes tests, so now I want to upload it to an FPGA.

I am new to this FPGA world.  I have a Zybo Zynq 7000 given to me by a friend, but getting the tools from Xilinx needed to upload verilog to it is quite a user-hostile experience.  I am amazed that I have a piece of hardware but I have to buy a license to use the software to communicate with it; further this license seems to terminate rather rapidly and constrain me to only certain machines etc.

The open source yosys etc. suite of tools looks very promising, especially as integrated by the APIO project: https://github.com/FPGAwars/apio , however it works only with certain FGPAs.

I am not familiar with the various FPGAs listed, so I do not know if which are powerful enough to host (1) an integer RISC-V-64 CPU, (2) plus my additional functionality when I get to that.  My additional functionality will likely more than double the complexity of a RISC-V-64 chip, so I think I likely need the most powerful FPGA that yosys / IceStorm will handle.

Could someone please recommend such a yosys / IceStorm compatible FPGA?

Answer (score 0):

Yosys + XRay can target UltraScale+ devices, to an extend.

As for the Xilinx tools, you do not need to buy a licence, WebPack free license is enough for Zynq7000.

For the yosys+nextpnr-xilinx flow, see https://github.com/gatecat/nextpnr-xilinx